# Win32 API Sample Code gives Compiling error "error C2065: 'HINSTANCE': undeclared identifier"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I was following the guide on Microsoft about Windows programming https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows and after learning the concepts and the naming conventions I got to the coding part.

this the code I copied from the guide.

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif 

#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PWSTR pCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

but when I try to compile this it gives me an error about `WINAPI` and `HINSTANCE undefined`

I know that `windows.h` contains child files that I think can't be included individually but when I try to include `windef.h` after `windows.h` as it contains the `typedef` of `WINAPI` it gives alot of other errors but the `WINAPI` error is gone.

I am using VS2017 version 15.9.36 With Windows 10 SDK (10.0.17134.0)
[Visual Studio installed packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A03zu.png)

I am so new to windows programming and idk what am I doing wrong I hope I provided enough info.

Comment: Possibly a configuration error in your project, or (clutching at straws, here) an accidental definition of the `_WINDOWS_` macro? (Normally, `_WINDOWS` is defined for Windows projects but, with the extra underscore at the end, that will prevent most of the `Windows.h` file content from being used.)

Comment: But it seems that _WINDOWS is correctly defined in my project.